# Laissez faire memory management

Tags: memory, interpreters, memory-usage

I noticed that various scripting language interpreters leak memory even for very simple programs, like the canonical "Hello world!" program. To illustrate the problem with examples:

**Perl 5.22** leaks 388,809 bytes.

`use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
print("Hello World!\n");`

**Python 3.5** leaks 456,502 bytes.

`print("Hello World!")`

**SpiderMonkey 24** leaks 79,325 bytes.

`print("Hello World!")`

*(Valgrind shows memory leaked by SpiderMonkey as still reachable, but in 66 blocks - so it can't be excused by leaked [emergency exception buffer in libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64535))*

Apart from the fact that in large programs memory management may become difficult and bugs appear, during my research, I discovered another reason for these leaks: *Why bother with releasing memory if the OS will reclaim it after the process ends?*

However, what if the process happens to be a long-running one? Is such an approach to memory management acceptable?

**EDIT:** I do believe my question is not a duplicate of [How important it is to fix memory leaks?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/214319/how-important-it-is-to-fix-memory-leaks). That question is about memory leaks in user applications. I asked about memory leaks in "runtime environments" which do not have the comfort of knowing how exactly they will be used and therefore cannot make assumptions such as "we can let it leak, because the leaking function is called only once" or similar.

**EDIT 2:** (as suggested by @kdgregory) The question is not about *the applications* managing their memory, but about the memory management of the runtime itself (be it some internal data structures, temporary objects etc.). The Valgrind (which I used to check for leaks) does only see the runtime-level structures, and not application-level structures.

Comment: "acceptable" in this context is very subjective.

Comment: @MetaFight Is it? I don't know if a runtime environment can make many assumptions (e.g. "processes will be only short-running so memory reclaiming can be left as OS job") about the programs that will run on them. It should strive to be as "clean" as possible IMO.

Comment: @lxrec I am running the interpreters under Valgrind.

Comment: Memory leaks in long running processes are mainly a problem is the leaks accumulate. Your examples might well be due to the runtime not bothering to run the GC because the program terminates before the GC triggers, whereas for a long running process the GC would eventually trigger.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Good point.

Comment: How do you know those are memory leaks and not resources that would have been released by the memory manager at a later time, if you had allowed the program to run longer? How do know it's not a resource pool?

Comment: "I don't know if a runtime environment can make many assumptions" – Sure, a scripting interpreter knows *for sure* that it will run not longer than its host, and it can *assume* that it will run much shorter than that. I.e. the overwhelming majority of shell scripts runs for fractions of a second and allocates only a few kb of memory, so a shell script interpreter can get away with a crappy, but simple memory manager (or none at all), at least in batch mode. Many "toy" language implementations don't have a garbage collector at all, and you would be surprised how "useful" programs you can still

Comment: … run on them without running out of memory.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I am not convinced. Well, of course, toy language implementations can do without a memory manager and can run "useful" programs. However: what about web applications written in Django (i.e. Python) or Rails (i.e. Ruby)? The interpreter cannot make the assumption that the program will be short running. I have also seen a program written in Perl which would run for a few days at times. Is that considered short-running?

Comment: You might want to edit your question to be more clear that Valgrind checks for leaks in the runtime itself, rather than application-level resources that are subject to garbage collection. Although to be honest, I don't think this question is answerable without a maintainer coming here and saying "we've never run Valgrind on our code, so we have no clue what leaks might be in it."

Comment: Or their reaction might be more dramatic: in a previous job, we regularly ran Purify (an equivalent checker) on our product. Along the way we discovered some runtime leaks. Oracle was happy when we reported leaks in their library. But another division of our company, which produced a messaging product, responded by saying "you have no right to be looking at that code."

Comment: All Ruby and Python engines I know of have automatic memory managers. YARV has a fairly simple mark-and-sweep tracing collector. Rubinius has a tracing collector based on the Immix paper. CPython has a reference counting collector combined with a simple mark-and-sweep tracing collector. PyPy has a region-based collector, I think. JRuby, IronRuby, Jython, and IronPython don't have their own memory managers, they rely on their host platform. Rakudo Perl is similar, I believe, it also doesn't manage its own memory but relies on the host (Parrot, Moar, or JVM).

Comment: @JörgWMittag I am aware that they do have automatic memory managers. Do you think it is acceptable for an automatic memory manager (or any other part) embedded in a runtime environment to cause memory leaks? I mean, if I designed an interpreter I would make it a high priority that the memory manager prevent memory leaks of any kind - no matter the lifetime of a program, or how many interpreter features it uses.

Comment: @Mael why do you think it's leaking memory? Just still holding on to memory at time A doesn't mean it won't "get around" to garbage collecting it "at some point". Most garbage collectors collect more agressively when they are running low on memory and less agressively when they aren't  **which is good behaviour**

Comment: If you want to know it its really leaking put each of those in an infinite loop. A leaking system will show a linear growth of memory usage. A properly GCed program will show an initial linear growth then a flat section (or oscillation about a set point).

Comment: @RichardTingle I believe he is aware about that, but the question he is asking is more about the memory leaked during the initialization of certain routines rather than the memory leaked during those routines.